# What does "Zukunst" in "Zurück in die Zukunst" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

I’ve read in the news that some German music band called SDP made a new album "[Zurück in die **Zukunst**](http://hiphop-releases.de/deutschrap/sdp-zurueck-in-die-zukunst)".

Why is it not *Zukunft* instead of *Zukunst*? What does this mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a play on words. *Zurück in die Zukunft* is the German title of a popular movie series (*Back to the future*). I guess they replaced *f* with *s* to mix in the word *Kunst* (*art*). What this might mean is left to the reader’s interpretation …

**Edit**: Thinking about it, I wonder whether it is intentional or purely coincidental that in old blackletter fonts the [*s* letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) used in *Kunst* (*Kunſt*) looks quite similar (to the untrained eye, at least) to the letter *f*. [Example on Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=e_9IAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA332&dq=kunst+zukunft&hl=de&sa=X&ei=vaRfVYizFoavsAH4mYGQCw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=kunst%20zukunft&f=false)

Comment: It's not a font problem, see [here](http://hiphop-releases.de/deutschrap/sdp-zurueck-in-die-zukunst).

Comment: @MartinSchröder I never meant it to be a font *problem*. I only *speculated* whether the similarity of the two words when using such a font might have something to do with it. They don't seem to use that similarity in their graphics material, but this doesn't exclude other kind of relationships, e.g. initially inspiring one member of the band for that word game. But as I wrote: it can also be just pure coincidence.

Comment: They seem to use word games a lot. The name 'SDP' reads at a first glance  like the german political party 'SPD' (or even 'PDS', a historical party name). The previous album was named 'Bunte Rapublik Deutschpunk', featuring the word 'rap' mixed into 'Republik'. And the current album's subtitle 'Angriff der Riesenohrwürmer' may be mixed from 'Angriff der Klonkrieger' (StarWars) , 'Im Land der Raketenwürmer' (A movie called 'Tremors') and 'Ohrwurm' (earwig, used for a catchy tune that one can't get out of his head).

Comment: I guess someone who calls hirself optim1st will understand these wordplays :)

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk Hi! Yeah, I totally understand this word game, but it's always a chance of something deeper since it's a foreign language :)

Comment: I wonder whether they weren’t aware of the possibility to underline the wordplay (and the context, as blackletter fonts are from a different time) by using a long s or whether they thought their audience would not understand or appreciate it.

Comment: Slightly off-topic comment: I see that a few people here are saying "word game", which I presume is being directly translated from "Wortspiel". This is entirely understandable but, as a native English speaker, I would call it a "play on words", or perhaps a "pun" :)

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for the hint. At least in the answer there is now the correct wording.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Do the English native speakers never use the "word game" at all? In Russian it also would be "игра слов" (Wortspiel).

Comment: @optim1st: Why are you addressing me with that comment? But as far as I can tell, *word game* is not used in English in the sense of *wordplay.* I attribute this to a certain distiniction between *game* and *play* that exists in English. In fact *[word game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_game)* is used to describe games that centre around words like Scrabble.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sorry, I've mixed up the person. But you've answered to my question, thank you.